# Remote debug or local debug with tomcat embedded in Spring boot

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat, vaadin

I am working on a new project which embedded a tomcat with the dependency spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.5.3 (into vaadin-spring-boot-starter).
I am building my project into a .jar, and launching it with "mvn spring-boot:run".

But because of the embedded tomcat, I am unable to use the debug mode with Eclipse.

I have already try to launch a remote debug session, with :

```
MAVEN_OPTS= -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

Eclipse connects itself well, but breakpoints are not working and it shows me only one thread, without any more informations.

So, do you have any idea how can I make it works ?
Thanks you for your time !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running application using `mvn spring-boot:run` you can attach debugger like this:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000"
```

By providing `spring-boot.run.jvmArguments` system property.

Alternatively, you can build application first and then run it using the following command:

```
java -jar app.jar -Dagentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000
```

When you provide debugger configuration using `MAVEN_OPTS`, the debugger is attached to the Maven process, however, the application is running in a separate Java process without a debugger attached.

Comment: It connects well, but my remote debugger (on eclipse) doesn't stop at breakpoints. It looks like it just connect but do nothing. My remote detect it is an openJDK 64x, and detect the Thread[main] running, can terminate server when debugger stop. But it won't stop or showing anything about debug.

Comment: @Robyn.D I edited my answer, please check

Comment: And it works perfectly well now ! Thank you very much :) The "spring-boot.run.jvmArguments" property did the trick

Comment: Had the same issue, but providing this JVM property did not help to activate the breakpoints. I am starting the Vaadin app using the mvnw start-up script and added the JVM property like this to the last line: `exec "$JAVACMD" \
  $MAVEN_OPTS \
  -classpath "$MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar" \
  "-Dmaven.home=${M2_HOME}" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=${MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR}" \
  "-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=\"-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000\"" \
  ${WRAPPER_LAUNCHER} $MAVEN_CONFIG "$@"`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to debug a Spring Boot application from an IDE is to not use Maven at all but instead directly launch the `main` method from the `@SpringBootApplication` class.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is described here:
https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17519592/debug-with-intellij
This solution also helped me get around the problem of connecting the remote debugger, but breakpoints not being reached (see my comment above).

You can add a JVM arg to the config params of the plugin, like this:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- my edits start -->
        <configuration>
            <jvmArguments>
                -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
            </jvmArguments>
        </configuration>
        <!-- my edits end -->
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a third solution, I have installed Spring Tools 4 on the Eclipse Marketplace.
It makes me able to launch a @SpringBootApplication in debug mode, like Leif Astrand said, but with an IHM (Boot Dashboard).